# Open3.popen3 + gpg + encoding as iso-8859-1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gnupg

im having a real problem getting a file to encode properly.
the file contains a latin character "\u00FD" and the people importing this file need it to be encoded as iso-8859-1 not us-ascii.

im not sure what to do with this.  i've tried several methods that i was hoping would work, but im coming up empty handed.

here is some code.

```
test_delimiter = "\u00FD"

content = Array.new

Model.each do |m|
  content << m.some_col
  content << test_delimiter
  content << m.another_col
end


Open3.popen3 "gpg --trust-model always -r 'some_key' -a -e > some_file.csv.txt" do |stdin, stdout, stderr|
  stdin.write content.join
  stdin.close
end
```

regardless of what i do- running file -I some_file.csv.txt in terminal returns charset=us-ascii

initially when i started the tests i was running

```
 file = File.open("some_file.csv","w:iso-8859-1")
 file.write content.join
 file.close
```

and it was working without a problem.

is there a way i can make this happen with Open3.popen3 and gpg?

thanks in advance

EDIT: this is for ruby 1.9.3 rails 3.2.x

Comment: i think you will have to tell gpg to do that. did you have a look at the `--p12-charset` param? http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg-devel/Input-and-Output.html

Comment: i did not. i ended up reading the file (File.open) and writing the file again with the encoding. but im going to try your suggestion now.  thank you.

Comment: also you can try: `stdin.write content.join.encode('iso-8859-1')`